# How to use [ngStyle] to apply styling to a selected element in *ngFor?

Tags: angular, ng-style

I'm going to have multiple buttons and the need to use forms to style the buttons. Each button should be able to get its own specific styles. In the example below, I'm attempting to click a button in the list to select it, and then click a separate button to apply styles to the selected button using `[ngStyle]`. Everything seems to be working so far except the new styles via `[ngStyle]` are not being applied and I see no errors.

```
<div *ngFor="let button of buttons;">
    <button class="button" [class.selected]="button === selectedButton" [ngStyle]="buttonStyles" (click)="selectButton(button)">{{button.text}}</button>
</div>

<button (click)="changeNgStyle()">changeNgStyle</button>
```

```
selectedButton?;

selectButton(button): void {
    this.selectedButton = button;
}

changeNgStyle() {
    this.selectedButton.buttonStyles = {
        'color':'blue', 
        'font-weight':'bold',
        'background-color': 'red'
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot see any `buttonStyles` declared in your ts code, please try the following:

```
[ngStyle]="selectedButton?.buttonStyles"
```

So, your html should be like:

```
<button class="button" [class.selected]="button === selectedButton" [ngStyle]="selectedButton?.buttonStyles" (click)="selectButton(button)">{{button.text}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't quite clear, but it appears the style is wrapped in the `buttonStyles` property of the `selectedButton` variable. So shouldn't the `ngStyle` be bound to `selectedButton.buttonStyles`?

Try the following

```html
<button 
  class="button" 
  [class.selected]="button === selectedButton" 
  [ngStyle]="selectedButton.buttonStyles" 
  (click)="selectButton(button)"
>{{button.text}}</button>
```